# How can I save my Dia drawing as a custom shape?

Tags: dia

I've got an existing simple Dia drawing and would like to turn it into a custom Dia *.shape to use in other diagrams. How can I get my drawing into Dia's toolbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new shapes to Dia is described step-by-step here: http://dia-installer.de/howto/create_shape/index.html.en